# Checkbox not showing in table after AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have in `defi.php` a form with the following AJAX call:

```
$('#def').submit(function (event) {
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('defidos.php', data)
            .success(function (result) {
                $('#dos').html(result);
            })
            .error(function () {
                console.log('Error loading page');
            })
    return false;
});
```

`defidos.php` has the following table row which contains a check box:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="seleccion[]" value="<?php echo $id_plantilla; ?>"  /> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $faquerynm['cve_plaza']; ?> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $desc_cat; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $faquerynm['tiempo']; ?>  
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $faquerynm['situacion']; ?>  
    </td>   
    <td>
        <?php echo $div_areal; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

After the call the checkbox is not shown.

If I put the checkbox outside the table it shows correctly.

Comment: Your value is probably incorrect.

Comment: Nop i tried assigning value="0"

Comment: Where is `<div id="dos">` in your html ? we can not help you if you give us that half the information

Comment: Chances are that the html() function is overwriting the markup of the checkbox, but as zlen pointed out, we can't really tell without more info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using css , creating the table  with divs .

```
    #container {
        display: table;
    }

    #row  {
        display: table-row;
    }

    #left, #right, #middle {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .titulos {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

With this the checkbox shows correctly